# Big-O for T(N) = 2T(N − 1) + N, T(1) = 2

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

How to get ***`big-O`*** for this?

```
T(N) = 2T(N − 1) + N, T(1) = 2
```

I got two variants of answer ***`O(2^N)`*** or ***`O(N^2)`***, but I am not sure how to solve it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide `T(N)` by `2^N` and name the result:

```
S(N) = T(N)/2^N
```

From the definition of `T(N)` we get

```
S(N) = S(N-1) + N/2^N                                  (eq.1)
```

meaning that `S(N)` increases, but quickly converges to a constant (since `N/2^N -> 0`). So,

```
T(N)/2^N -> constant
```

or

```
T(N) = O(2^N)
```

---

**Detailed proof**

In the comment below Paul Hankin suggests how to complete the proof. Take eq.1 and sum from `N=2` to `N=M`

```
sum_{N=2}^M S(N) = sum_{N=2}^M S(N-1) + sum_{N=2}^M N/2^N
                 = sum_{N=1}{M-1} S(N) + sum_{N=1}^{M-1} (N-1)/2^{N-1}
```

thus, after canceling terms with indexes `N = 2`, `3`, ..., `M-1`, we get

```
S(M) = S(1) + sum_{N=1}^M N/2^N - M/2^M
```

and since the series on the right converges (because its terms are bounded by `1/N^2` for `N>>1` which is known to converge), `S(M)` converges to a finite constant.

Answer (score -1):

It's a math problem and Leandro Caniglia is right.

let b(n) = T(n) / 2^n

thus b(n) = b(n-1) + n / 2^n = b(n-2) + n / 2^n + (n-1) / 2^(n-1) ....

i / 2^i is less than 1 for every integer i

So the sum of them has limit and must smaller than some constant.

thus b(n) < C.

thus T(n) < 2^n * C.

It is obvious that T(n) >= 2^n.

So T(n) is O(2^n)